# make a batch script foward an IP

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, forwarding

Hi so my coworker requested if I could make a script. I am sure what I want it to do and wrote some pseudo code in bash style now of course this not useable for him since he is on Windows. So I tried to implement in a .bat script now here is where my knowledge comes a bit short. What I need the script to do is to connect to a certain VPN-ip if that is not avaible the localsystem should foward it to another VPN so he doesn't need to worry about it. Either one of 2 should always be reachable. But they are never at the same time. This is for test tooling.

Pseudo bashcode

```
    while true 
  do
  From local if 
    10.10.1.15 avaible connect to it 
    else
    10.168.84.47 connect to it
  elseif
   try to connect to 10.10.1.15 again && verify that'
                else 
                    echo 'error device over VPN unavaible'
```

My Attempted batch script, I am pretty sure that what I have now is not gonna work

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set ipaddr=%1
:loop
set state=down
for /f "tokens=5,6,7" %%a in ('ping -n 1 !ipaddr!') do (
    if "x%%b"=="xunreachable." goto :endloop
    if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%c"=="x1,"  set state=up
)
:endloop
echo.Link is !state!
ping -n 6 10.10.1.15 >nul: 2>nul:
goto :loop
endlocal


IF EXIST 10.10.1.15 (
    is reacheable connect
) ELSE (
    netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 connectaddress=10.10.1.15 fowardaddress=10.168.84.47
)
```

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know, you can just try to find "ttl=" to determine success/fail for a ping without worrying about all those tokens and different versions of cmd.  I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

**untested**

```
set ip=127.0.0.1

rem 2 pings waiting 900ms for a reply
ping -n 2 -w 900 %ip%|find /i "ttl=">nul || goto :fail

rem If we get here then the ping succeeded
rem do what you want here

goto :eof

:fail
rem If we get here then the ping failed.
rem do what you want here

goto :eof
```

The `||` operator basically means "if the previous command fails then do this".

Comment: Yes, searching for `TTL=` is the most reliable to check for a successful connection, as also described here: https://ss64.com/nt/ping.html